# How can I auto-increment the value in a dictionary when there is a difference?

Tags: python, dictionary

It's much easier to explain my doubts with an example:

I have a list with dictionaries of this type,

```
[
    {
     'portal_id': 5, 
     'url_imovel': 'asd.pt', 
     'url_photos': {0: 'pfoto1.pt', 1: 'pphoto2.pt'}, 
     'total_photos': 2
    }, 
    {
     'portal_id': 5, 
     'url_imovel': 'asd2.pt', 
     'url_photos': {0: 'pfoto12.pt', 1: 'pphoto22.pt'}, 
     'total_photos': 2
    },
    {
     'portal_id': 5, 
     'url_imovel': 'foo.pt', 
     'url_photos': {0: 'fotofoo1.pt', 1: 'photofoo2.pt', 1: 'photofoo3.pt'}, 
     'total_photos': 3
    }
]
```

The dictionary is generated as follows:

```
all_im_fotos = []

    im_fotos = {
        "portal_id" : 5,
        "url_imovel" : str(),
        "url_photos" : dict(),
        "total_photos": int()
    }

    urls = "asd.pt"
    photos_url = ["pfoto1.pt", "pphoto2.pt"]

    im_fotos["url_imovel"] = urls
    for i in range(len(photos_url)):
        im_fotos["url_photos"].update({i: photos_url[i]})
    im_fotos["total_photos"] = len(im_fotos["url_photos"])

    all_im_fotos.append(im_fotos)

    ... same process ...
```

My question is, how can I compare the insertion of new values. My goal is to create a new dictionary that just insert new values, increasing the index of imfotos. For example:

```
difference = []
new_imovel = "asd.pt"
new_url_photos = ["pfoto1.pt", "pfoto3.pt"]
```

There is a new photo for the url "asd.pt", so we should add the difference by auto incrementing the index, resulting in:

```
[
        {
         'portal_id': 5, 
         'url_imovel': 'asd.pt', 
         'url_photos': {0: 'pfoto1.pt', 1: 'pphoto2.pt', 2: 'pfoto3.pt'}, 
         'total_photos': 3
        }
]
```

How can I make this as simple as possible? is it possible to save this dictionary as a json file in order to perform the same process later?

Comment: You haven't mentioned any things about but you are using `web-scraping`. Please either mention `web-scraping` in your question or remove that tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is it possible to save this dictionary as a json file in order to perform the same process later?

you can use `json.dumps()` to convert python `dict` to json, and use `json.loads()` to  read json file to python `dict`.

## link:

- https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-convert-python-dictionary-to-json/
- https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/convert-json-to-dictionary-in-python/

## code:

```
datas = [
    {
     'portal_id': 5, 
     'url_imovel': 'asd.pt', 
     'url_photos': {0: 'pfoto1.pt', 1: 'pphoto2.pt'}, 
     'total_photos': 2
    }, 
    {
     'portal_id': 5, 
     'url_imovel': 'asd2.pt', 
     'url_photos': {0: 'pfoto12.pt', 1: 'pphoto22.pt'}, 
     'total_photos': 2
    },
    {
     'portal_id': 5, 
     'url_imovel': 'foo.pt', 
     'url_photos': {0: 'fotofoo1.pt', 1: 'photofoo2.pt', 2: 'photofoo3.pt'}, 
     'total_photos': 3
    }
]

new_imovel = "asd.pt"
new_url_photos = ["pfoto1.pt", "pfoto3.pt"]
for data in datas:
    if data["url_imovel"] == new_imovel:
        for photo in new_url_photos:
            if not photo in data['url_photos'].values():
                data['url_photos'].update({len(data['url_photos']):photo})
                data['total_photos']+=1
print(datas)
```

## result:

```
[
    {
        "portal_id": 5,
        "url_imovel": "asd.pt",
        "url_photos": {0: "pfoto1.pt", 1: "pphoto2.pt", 2: "pfoto3.pt"},
        "total_photos": 3,
    },
    {
        "portal_id": 5,
        "url_imovel": "asd2.pt",
        "url_photos": {0: "pfoto12.pt", 1: "pphoto22.pt"},
        "total_photos": 2,
    },
    {
        "portal_id": 5,
        "url_imovel": "foo.pt",
        "url_photos": {0: "fotofoo1.pt", 1: "photofoo2.pt", 2: "photofoo3.pt"},
        "total_photos": 3,
    },
]
```